# i cant put windows 10 after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

i have tried to put windows 10 after installing ubuntu cause i by accident didnt know what i was reading and put delete the hard drive and install ubuntu the day i downloaded ubuntu after quite some time, but for some reason my flashed drive doesnt work, i go to the bios settings i enabled UEFI and even put legacy but just doesnt work i even tried windows 11 ISO but doenst work and i think its a problem with the bios,i have an hp laptop if it helps,and also for some reason i have the grub menu to start when i boot, hope someone helps me!

Comment: Ubuntu cannot fix a BIOS problem.